# Using Perforce to get file info

Tags: perforce

Is there any way I can get the following output from perforce for files under a certain directory? I'd like: file name, last modified by username, last modified date, created by username, creation date.

So far I've only been able to get a list of changelists and their descriptions, but then I can't pipe that into another P4 command to do anything else with it. I'm in Windows by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either go with `p4 fstat` and a subsequent `p4 describe` or you could parse the output of `p4 filelog`:

```
$ p4 filelog Rakefile
//depot/path/to/Rakefile
... #9 change 421932 edit on 2011/10/27 by user@client (text) '....'
... #8 change 421210 edit on 2011/10/24 by user@client (text) '....'
... #7 change 419771 edit on 2011/10/17 by user@client (text) '....'
... #6 change 393076 edit on 2011/05/26 by user@client (text) '....'
... #5 change 374172 edit on 2011/02/11 by user@client (text) '....'
... #4 change 374083 edit on 2011/02/11 by user@client (text) '....'
... #3 change 374042 edit on 2011/02/11 by user@client (text) '....'
... #2 change 373901 edit on 2011/02/10 by user@client (text) 'need ci/reporter rake-task'
... #1 change 359972 add on 2010/11/23 by user@client (text) 'added first version'
```

`user@client` will be the username and the name of the client workspace. Revision #1 is obviously the creation date, and the revision on top of the list (#9 here) is the last modified. So basically you have to parse the first line that begins with '...' for the last modified stuff and the last line that begins with '...' for the creation information.

Comment: Use `p4 filelog -i` to get the branched history of the file.

Comment: I'm trying to create a script that lists all files created by $user